# What happens if we have both jackson-jaxrs-json-provider and jersey-media-json-binding.jar in the class path at /WEB-INF/lib directory?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jersey, jax-rs

I am working on a web application managed by Apache ant builder. We recently upgraded jersey from 2.17 to 2.35 and all the related dependencies in the class path. After upgrading i noticed one error where the PSOT method argument is populated as null.

Did some digging to solve this issue, found jersey-media-json-binding.jar might be causing the issue. Removed it from class path, and everything works fine.

But I am unable to figure why did the issue cause in the first place, what is the use of this jersey-media-json-binding.jar library.

Does jersey-media-json-binding.jar and jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.12.2.jar provide the same functionality, which is causing the issue?

Comment: @Pshemo Thanks for the answer, i figured it out once i wrote the sample code for stack overflow, hence deleted the question since it was rejected by Stack overflow team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSON-B](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html#json.json-b) is the new *default* provider. If you have it on the classpath (without explicit registration of other providers), it *will* be used. The default used to be [MOXy](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html#json.json-b). If you want [Jackson](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html#json.jackson) to be used regardless of which provider is on the classpath, just register the `JacksonFeature` with your application. All three of these providers are used for JSON support, but they all have different behaviors in regards to (de)serialization. Also, all of these provider modules have auto-registration, meaning you don't have to explicitly register them. But there *is* predefined behavior as to which one will take priority (if more than one is present). So if you want a specific one to be used, regardless of which are on the classpath, just register its feature (i.e. `JacksonFeature`, `JsonBindingFeature`, `MoxyJsonFeature`).

Comment: If i am understanding it correctly, in my case when I removing the jason-b jar from my classs path, I am basically de-registering it, and since I also have jackson-jaxrs-json-provider , my application will use it as provider and (de)serialize the requests and responses of the application?

Also i do not have to explicitly register JacksonFeature right using JacksonFweature.class right? Since this has auto-register capability.

Comment: Pretty much....